# When a Series 4 Apple Watch contacts emergency services due to fall detection, what do the emergency responders hear?

Tags: apple-watch

[Per Apple's docs:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208944)

> ### What happens if your Apple Watch detects that you're immobile
>
> If your Apple Watch detects that you're immobile for about a minute, it begins a 30-second countdown, while tapping you on the wrist and sounding an alert. The alert gets louder, so that you or someone nearby can hear it. If you don't want to call emergency services, tap Cancel. When the countdown ends, your Apple Watch automatically contacts emergency services.
>
> When the call connects, ***your Apple Watch plays an audio message that informs emergency services that your Apple Watch detected a hard fall and then it shares your current location as latitude and longitude coordinates.***

I'm interested in the content of that audio message. I'm guessing it may be a synthesized voice, ala Siri, but I'm wondering if anyone has a recording of what the watch says to the 911 operator when triggered in this way?

Comment: I won't put this in an answer unless I can track down the exact script (or even a recording), but it's *something* along the lines of *Apple Watch announcement. A person has fallen heavily.* Followed by the coordinates of where the fall took place.